# How to change default background color of selected date in Input type date

Tags: javascript, html, css, datepicker

Is there a way to change background-color of selected date in input type date. By default it's blue .

[image]

So i want to change this blue background color on 5th.

I've tried searching on Stackoverflow but there is no mention of this.

Comment: We have the CSS [accent-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color) property, but it unfortunately doesn't apply to date inputs.

Comment: If you're using the built-in browser datepicker I don't think you get much control, since the UI is entirely browser-dependent. Use a JS/HTML datepicker widget to get fine control.